# Calculate occurrences and insert into json on the fly in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like below

```
id |date                   |browser
---+———————————————————————+——————————————————————-
101|2024-03-12 00:00:00.000|Chrome |
102|2024-03-12 00:00:00.000|Firefox|
103|2024-03-13 00:00:00.000|Chrome |
104|2024-03-13 00:00:00.000|Firefox|
105|2024-03-13 00:00:00.000|Brave  |
106|2024-03-14 00:00:00.000|Chrome |
107|2024-03-14 00:00:00.000|Firefox|
108|2024-03-14 00:00:00.000|Edge   |
```

I want to count the occurances and insert the number of occurances in another database like below (into jsonb column). The browser is just as example of a string and can have many different type of values (i.e. it is not an enum type, so the values are unknown.)

```
id |date                   |json_count
---+———————————————————————+———————————————————————————————————————-
101|2024-03-12 00:00:00.000|{“Chrome”: 1, “Firefox”: 1}            |
102|2024-03-13 00:00:00.000|{“Chrome”: 1, “Firefox”: 1, “Brave”: 1}|
103|2024-03-14 00:00:00.000|{“Chrome”: 1, “Firefox”: 1, “Edge”: 1} |
```

How do i achieve this in a sql query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to count the occurances by date and browser using `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()`, then apply jsonb_object_agg to aggregate browser/count pairs as a JSON object using [`jsonb_object_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) :

```
select min(id) as id, date, json_object_agg(browser, cnt) as json_count
from (
  select date, browser, min(id) as id, count(*) as cnt
  from mytable
  group by date, browser
)
group by date;
```

Results :

```
id  date                json_count
101 2024-03-12 00:00:00 {"Chrome": 1, "Firefox": 1}
106 2024-03-14 00:00:00 {"Edge": 1, "Chrome": 1, "Firefox": 1}
103 2024-03-13 00:00:00 {"Brave": 1, "Chrome": 1, "Firefox": 1}
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/z1Nj-_oh)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A follow up question - can a continuous aggregate view or a materialized view be created on top of this so that data gets aggregated by a aggregate policy?

Comment: You can create a materialized view, but it requires refreshing each time there's an update to your table.